# Realm JS speed with React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I want to use RealmJS with React Native but it looks like it's very slow. What I do is just simple insert like this

```
realm.write(() => {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        realm.create(entity, data[i]);
    }
})
```

And if there is more than few records, UI freezes (a lot). I know there is only one javascript thread but I was expecting that RealmJS is written in native code and javascript library is only wrapper, maybe that is wrong assumption.
I feel like I am doing something wrong because if this is how RealmJS works, it's kind of useless.

So, how to speed up this?

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess, that you should create the rows in a batch, not call insert per record.

Comment: Well yeah, but how to do that? I can't find anything about batches in realm.

Comment: What sort of sizes are we talking about here? You are right that Realm tends to be very fast, so this does sound a bit odd. Be aware that debugging React Native with Realm tends to be very slow. This is something we are aware of and will fix -- see [this issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/491)

Comment: It's usually small objects but it can be a lot of them.

Comment: I realized that we are using Realm very extensively and we would eventually reach its limitations anyway, so I decided to implement native wrapper for RealmSwift. It will not be just a wrapper but it will also have some logic and probably data synchronization with server. Do you see any hickups with using native module wrapper for RealmSwift?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no.

Comment: Am experiencing the same issue. Am using realm on chat application as an offline first option. Every time their is an update to the Database with just a single record their is a noticeable UI freeze. @trubi Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: We stopped using Realm. We had some problems with Realm in previous native app and now when making react native prototype I am using sqlite and it's way better. Depends a lot of your use case but for us it proved to be much better.

Comment: Thanks. Will most likely follow the same route as you.